# Setting the Width / Height on custom TShape

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have created a new unit like so and it should be a custom TShape.

```
unit MachineShape;


interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, extctrls,myDataModule,Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type

TMachine = class(TShape)
     count : Integer;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure PlaceShape(sizeW,sizeH :integer; name, order,asset : string);
  end;
implementation

    Procedure PlaceShape(sizeW,sizeH :integer; name, order,asset : string);
    begin

    end;

end.
```

next i pass this to the procedure

```
MachineShape.TMachine.PlaceShape(44,49,'CM402','first','123/33/123');
```

How do i set in the procedure to set the shape size as 44 width and 49 height?

I have tried to do TMachine.Width  but it does not work?
thanks
glen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared `PlaceShape` to be an instance method and so need to implement it as such:

```
Procedure TMachine.PlaceShape(sizeW,sizeH :integer; name, order,asset : string);
begin
  Width := sizeW;
  Height := sizeH;
  ....
end;
```

You declared a function

```
Procedure PlaceShape(...);
```

that is not a method of the class.

This question suggests that you are missing some understanding of the Delphi object model. I refer you to the [relevant section of the language guide](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Methods) to fill in the missing knowledge.

I would also recommend that you use different names for your dimensions parameters. You should use `AWidth` and `AHeight` so that it is clear to future readers of the code that these parameters are going to be used to set the corresponding shape properties.

Comment: I get it now, for some reason when i did TMachine.  PlaceShape would not come up a compile / build fixed it ..  Thanks!